# Why content is not adding for each blog post

Tags: theme-development, loop

[my posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOL2S.jpg) Cant find all blogs.The wordpress see only home

```
<?php
    if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> 
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';
    endif;
?>
```

But there it working stable   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7olvEeBM2I?

Comment: This code looks O.K. to me. We'll need more information like where you're adding this code and if you actually have posts to display. Please[`edit` your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/266251/edit) by using edit link above ( or below your actual question ) to add in this additional information.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee already edited thank you.He shows only my homepage + content.I cant see my posts

Comment: When you go to `Settings -> Reading` do you have the `A static page` option selected and assigned? If so, maybe [read this over](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/static-front-page/).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thank you so much.I just changed posts page to Home and everything is worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are you have assigned a Static Front Page under `Settings -> Reading`. Whenever you assign a static page as your front-page, WordPress will display that page's content instead of your blog posts. You can assign a separate page as your "Posts Page" which, when displayed, will display your blog posts. You can either assign a Posts Page or change the setting to display your latest posts. For more information you may read:

[What is: Static Front Page](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/static-front-page/) by Syed Balkhi at WPBeginner